# Is $\{sin(n \pi/2N): n\in \mathbb{Z},0<n \leq N\}$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

I want to consider the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space generated by $\{sin(n \pi/2N):n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ where $N$ is a fix integer. My intuition is that if $N$ is not divisible by 3 then all possible generators are independent and if $N$ is divisible by 3 then we lose one generator since $sin(\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{1}{2}$.

I want to relate this to cyclotomic field extension. Thanks

Comment: I think the dimension should be $\frac{\varphi (4N)}{2}$ if my statement is correct.